# Is there a way to increase the CPU power given to a python program? (Python 3.5, Mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, cpu, cpu-usage

I have this program where you are a match and you must dodge falling snowflakes. Once you die, game over text is drawn on the screen while snowflakes continue to fall. Because the processes are simpler then (no keyboard input or moving the match, etc), the amount of CPU power used to execute the program decreases by about 4%. However, it takes longer to draw text and so the snowflakes all slowed down.

Is there a way to tell python to use more of the available CPU power in a program to make it run faster?

Here is the drawText method that I use:

```
def drawText(window, text, size, color, centerX, centerY):
    font=pygame.font.Font("DickensianChristmas.ttf", size)
    renderedText=font.render(str(text),True,color)
    textpos=renderedText.get_rect()
    textpos.centerx=centerX
    textpos.centery=centerY
    window.blit(renderedText, textpos)
```

This is the main code that runs normally:

```
while True:
    ticks += 1
    window.fill((200,200,200))

    #Increase difficulty with time
    if ticks%increaseRate == 0:
        snowFrequency *= 0.925
        snowSpeed += 0.125
        speed += 0.15

    #Generate Speed Boost
    if randint(1,speedFrequency) == 1 and not(speedOnScreen):
        speedOnScreen = True
        speedX = randint(0,1180)
        speedY = -120

    #Generate Shield
    if randint(1,shieldFrequency) == 1 and not(shieldOnScreen):
        shieldOnScreen = True
        shieldX = randint(0,1180)
        shieldY = -120

    #Move, draw, pick up, and delete speed boost
    if speedOnScreen:
        speedY += snowSpeed
        window.blit(speedBoost, (speedX,speedY))
        if 700 > speedY > 472 and matchX+15 > speedX > matchX-120:
            speedStart = ticks
            speedOnScreen = False
        if speedY > 700:
            speedOnScreen = False

    #Move, draw, pick up, and delete shield
    if shieldOnScreen:
        shieldY += snowSpeed
        window.blit(shield, (shieldX,shieldY))
        if 700 > shieldY > 472 and matchX+15 > shieldX > matchX-107:
            shieldStart = ticks
            shieldOnScreen = False
        if shieldY > 700:
            shieldOnScreen = False

    #Sheilding effect
    if ticks > shieldStart+shieldDuration:
        invincible = False
    else:
        invincible = True
        window.blit(pygame.transform.scale(shield, (55,60)), (1240,0))
        pygame.draw.line(window,(0,0,0),(1270,75),(1270, 75+shieldDuration-(ticks-shieldStart)),25)

    #Speed Boost Effect
    if ticks > speedStart+speedDuration:
        speed = baseSpeed
        tilt = tiltAmount
    else:
        speed = baseSpeed*2
        tilt = tiltAmount*1.5
        window.blit(pygame.transform.scale(speedBoost, (60,60)), (0,0))
        pygame.draw.line(window,(0,0,0),(30,75),(30, 75+speedDuration-(ticks-speedStart)),25)

    #Draw Score
    drawText(window, score, 96, (0,0,0), 650, 50)

    #Make snowflakes
    if randint(1,round(snowFrequency)) == 1:
        #                  IMAGE                          X-COORDINATE     Y-COORDINATE
        snowflakes.append([snowflakeImages[randint(0,5)], randint(0,1234), -64])
    #Move snowflakes (different kinds move differently)
    for flake in snowflakes:
        if flake[0] == snowflake1:
            flake[2] += snowSpeed*0.8
            flake[1] += randint(-2,1)
        elif flake[0] == snowflake2:
            flake[2] += snowSpeed*0.8
            flake[1] += randint(-1,2)
        elif flake[0] == snowflake3 or flake[0] == snowflake4:
            flake[2] += snowSpeed*1.25
            flake[1] += randint(-1,1)
        else:
            flake[2] += snowSpeed
            flake[1] += randint(-2,2)
        #Draw snowflakes
        #           IMAGE      LOCATION
        window.blit(flake[0], (flake[1],flake[2]))
        #Remove snowflakes that go off screen and increase score
        if flake[2] > 700:
            snowflakes.remove(flake)
            score += 1

        #Compensate for matches rotation
        addDegrees = 0
        if degrees < 0:
            addDegrees = degrees
        #Collision detection
        if 631 > flake[2] > 528 and matchX+15+addDegrees > flake[1] > matchX-64-addDegrees:
            if invincible:
                snowflakes.remove(flake)
                score += 2
            else:
                gameOver(window, snowflakes)

    #Detect quit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            done(window)

    #Match movement
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if (keys[K_a] or keys[K_LEFT]):
        if degrees > -tilt:
            degrees -= tiltSpeed
        matchX -= speed
    if (keys[K_d] or keys[K_RIGHT]):
        if degrees < tilt:
            degrees += tiltSpeed
        matchX += speed
    if not (keys[K_a] or keys[K_LEFT] or keys[K_d] or keys[K_RIGHT]):
        if degrees > 0:
            degrees -= tiltSpeed
            matchX += tiltSpeed*2
        if degrees < 0:
            degrees += tiltSpeed

    #Draw match
    window.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(match, degrees),(matchX, 592))
    #Move oss-screen side-switching
    if matchX < 15:
        matchX += 1300
    elif matchX > 1285:
        matchX -= 1300
    #Update display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Here is the code that is running slower after the game ends:

```
while True:
    window.fill((200,200,200))
    window.blit(burntOut4, (matchX,592))
    drawText(window, score, 96, (0,0,0), 650, 50)
    drawText(window, "GAME OVER!", 120, (0,0,0), 650, 350)
    if beatHS:
        drawText(window, "NEW HIGHSCORE!", 80, (0,0,0), 650, 450)
    else:
        drawText(window, "HIGHSCORE: "+highScore, 80, (0,0,0), 650, 450)
    if randint(1,round(snowFrequency)) == 1:
        snowflakes.append([snowflakeImages[randint(0,5)], randint(0,1234), -64])
    for flake in snowflakes:
        if flake[0] == snowflake1:
            flake[2] += snowSpeed*0.8
            flake[1] += randint(-2,1)
        elif flake[0] == snowflake2:
            flake[2] += snowSpeed*0.8
            flake[1] += randint(-1,2)
        elif flake[0] == snowflake3 or flake[0] == snowflake4:
            flake[2] += snowSpeed*1.25
            flake[1] += randint(-1,1)
        else:
            flake[2] += snowSpeed
            flake[1] += randint(-2,2)
        window.blit(flake[0], (flake[1],flake[2]))
        if flake[2] > 700:
            snowflakes.remove(flake)
    pygame.display.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit(0)
```

I have verified that it is the text drawing that slows it down by commenting it out. Might it also be possible to draw the text more efficiently rather than using more CPU?

Comment: you could use something like: pygame.display.set_mode(resolution, pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

Comment: Other than that I am not sure of any way to "tell" python to use more available CPU. There are also lots of ways to optimize games to keep at peak frame rate by optimizing the code itself

Comment: If text alone is slowing down your frame rate noticeably, there's a good chance something else is wrong that can be addressed rather than throwing more CPU at it. You should post your code.

Comment: @TrumpetDude Is it possible that you are being limited by memory or misk? You might be seeing minimal CPU usage because you are being bottle-necked by these components.

Comment: @TrumpetDude are the snowflakes pngs that are loaded at the beginning? meaning you are blitting a png to the screen

Comment: @The4thIceman They are gif images, but they are loaded at the beginning of the program before any looping starts. I don't see why they would make a difference though because the same images and variables are used in the main game loop and the game over loop.

Comment: @PrestonM Doubtful. The same images and variables are used in both loops and it is the the drawing of the text onto the screen that slows down the program. Snowflakes are deleted once they leave the screen to prevent memory filling up.I also don't think that it's a memory leak because the speed stays constant rather than slowing down and eventually crashing. I will post the drawText method that I use.

Comment: @TrumpetDude it makes a difference because over a longer period, blitting surface to surface is much faster than blitting image to surface.

Comment: @The4thIceman Hmm. How do I make them surfaces instead of images? Also, I'm still not sure that that is causing the problem because the change is sudden, and happens only when the game over text is being drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posit that once you start drawing text to screen, the amount of processing power is a bit much with drawing all the snowflakes as well. Blitting an image to a surface is much slower than blitting a surface to a surface. So with lots of snowflakes (in addition to the text), all that blitting is adding up.

for example (outside the game loop):

```
enemy_rect = get_image("enemy.png").get_rect()
enemy_surface = pygame.Surface((enemy_rect.width, enemy_rect.height), pygame.SRCALPHA)
enemy_surface.fill((0, 0, 0, 0))
enemy_surface.blit(get_image("enemy_reveal_camo.png"), enemy_rect)
```

so now when blit it to the screen (inside the game loop):

```
screen.blit(enemy_surface, (x, y))
```

is faster than:

```
enemy = get_image("enemy.png")  # outside game loop

screen.blit(enemy, (x, y))  # inside game loop
```

this may not fully solve your problem, but it will help with drawing efficiency. You are essentially pre-drawing the images. It is at least worth a try, it worked wonders for my game when I was drawing a bunch of individual images to the screen.

If you want to make the text drawing more efficient as well, pull the font loading and rendering outside of the game loop. So you can pre-render the text, and just update the locations when inside the code. Just like for images, you can pre-draw text to a surface outside the game loop since it is statically placed.

Always pre-draw as much as you can outside the game loop.

Comment: Oh, I see. That is not my problem (I think) because the images are set to variables at the beginning, not constantly reloaded. For example:  snowflake1 = pygame.image.load("snowflake1.gif") snowflake1 is the surface used later on in the program.

Comment: but snowflake1 is not a surface, it is an image, blit it to a surface snowflake1_surface and blit that in the game loop

Comment: I'll give it a shot when I have time, but overall speed is not the issue I am concerned with. All I am looking for is a way to draw the text more efficiently  in order to stop the program from slowing down, regardless of whether there are images.

Comment: sounds good. you can also pre-draw the text onto a surface as well outside the game loop since it is statically placed.